# selenium read message from WhatsApp timeout error

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

**I am getting this error while I'm running**

> File
> "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simon\chat\elements.py",
> line 126, in newest
> msgs = self.all(filterby)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simon\chat\elements.py",
> line 111, in all
> order_by_oldest = [self.child_class(e, self.driver) for e in self.__find_elements(locator)]   File
> "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simon\chat\elements.py",
> line 152, in __find_elements
> WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100).until(   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
> line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

*while Running the Folowing code the error happens while reading the new message from ehatsapp. why is the timeout happening? any ideas?*

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

from simon.accounts.pages import LoginPage
from simon.chat.pages import ChatPage
from simon.chats.pages import PanePage
from simon.header.pages import HeaderPage
# Creating the driver (browser)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python35\work\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

# Login
#       and uncheck the remember check box
#       (Get your phone ready to read the QR code)
#login_page = LoginPage(driver)
#login_page.load()
#
# Login
#       and uncheck the remember check box
#       (Get your phone ready to read the QR code)
login_page = LoginPage(driver)
login_page.load()
#login_page.remember_me = True
time.sleep(30)
# 1. Get all opened chats
#       opened chats are the one chats or conversations
#       you already have in your whatsapp.
#       IT WONT work if you are looking for a contact
#       you have never started a conversation.
print("========1=========")
pane_page = PanePage(driver)

# get all chats
print("========2=========")
#opened_chats = pane_page.opened_chats
print("=======")

name = "Sachin"  
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='{}']".format(name))
user.click()
print("========3=========")
time.sleep(10)
# 3. Read the last messages from your contact
chat_page = ChatPage(driver)
msgs = chat_page.messages.newest()
print(msgs)
```

Comment: can you share relevant HTML or URL ?

Comment: https://github.com/Fantaso/whatsapp-web

Comment: i tried using the code from above link

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, and i found the solution for my own.

maybe my solution will help you
https://twitter.com/jiwatomo_6/status/1493797280435953665

the "PanePage" class the pane detection module used/fired the wrong css selector(see screenshot). Maybe this will happen again on a different machine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).